# ABP localization resources does not return the intended value inside a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abp

After creating and adding a resource in a module:

```
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Resources
        .Add<TestResource>("en")
        .AddVirtualJson("/Path/To/Resource");
});
```

the json:

```
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "WelcomeMessage": "Hello {0}! welcome to this test application!",
    "TestText": "A test text in another resource defined in some module"
  }
}
```

using it inside an app service or a class is working fine and returns the specified value inside the json file when I run the application through HttpApi.Host project:

```
//injecting IStringLocalizer<TestResource> from ctor
string text = _localizer["TestText"];
//text will be: "A test text in another resource defined in some module"
```

but when I try to use it inside a unit test, it returns default value (the given key) as if the resource is not even registered:

```
[Fact]
public void should_get_text_in_TestResource()
{
    var localizer = GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<TestResource>>();


    string text = localizer["TestText"];

    text.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("A test text in another resource defined in some module");
}
```

But the weird thing is that the default resource that comes with template, it works just fine inside the unit tests:

```
[Fact]
public void should_get_text_in_AbpTestLocalizationResource()
{
    var localizer = GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<AbpTestLocalizationResource>>();

    string text = localizer["TestText"];

    text.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("A test text in default localization resource");
}
```

So I think it has to do with adding resources inside the unit test modules but I could not figure it out.

I created a sample of the problem that I have in the [github](https://github.com/aliBordbar1992/AbpTestResource)
(Unit tests are inside the AbpTestLocalization.Application.Tests project)

Note:
localized resources are not something that I want to test directly and it is not even necessary, my main question is how to make a class testable if it depends on resources other than the default resource? (An acutal use case is the TestTemplateProvider class inside the sample project). How come that the default resource gets recognized inside unit tests and not the others?

Comment: You can see similar test cases in ABP's source code.

See: 
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/test/Volo.Abp.Localization.Tests/Volo/Abp/Localization/AbpLocalization_Tests.cs

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that before, but I'm not sure how it could help solve my problem. Could you provide more details? And remember, I'm not trying to test my localized strings. If the question is not clear, tell me to elaborate more on that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the content of your "ProjectName.Domain.Shared.csproj" is erroneous.
We had the same issue, and fixed it by making sure the localization JSON files are embedded, and the reference to "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" is included:

```
    <ItemGroup>
       <EmbeddedResource Include="Localization\ProjectName\*.json" />
       <Content Remove="Localization\ProjectName\*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>    

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="6.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
```